# Bash wrapper keeping logs of each command give or take a UI-like experience

Tags: utilities

Is there any tool that provides the ability to execute a series of bash commands (think cloud server setup), keeping a formatted log of each command along with its output?

It would be somewhere between a tool like Ansible / Fabric and running a raw ugly bash script that spits everything out in a cognitively annoying way promoting human error in interpreting what has actually happened.

Of course I can write a program to do this, just checking if there's anything out there.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Are you looking for `history`? Or maybe `script`? What exactly do you mean by "keeping a log of each command"? The tool that executes a series of commands is called a shell script. What else do you need?

Comment: Multiple commands can be used over SSH and all commands are logged in .bash_history?